# When we should use RESOURCE_LOCAL and when use JTA?

Tags: java, jpa, jta

The flowing is my persistence xml file,So my question is ?
Is it wrong that i used RESOURCE_LOCAL or not ?

```
<persistence-unit name="default-persistence-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.Task</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/reports"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="clubsa"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```